# When was brehmsstrahlung discovered?

Tags: physics

I remember that not long ago wikipedia had somewhere info regarding the discovery of that phenomenon, but apparently all reference hasbeen removed.

Searching the web I found a serbian [site](http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/0354-7310/2007/0354-73100704100B.pdf) claiming that  Tesla discovered it in 1892, and published his finding in 1897. Tha is confirmend by Miles Mathis, but apparently he is not a reliable source.

Do you have any precise and reliable details on the issue?

Comment: It is "Bremsstrahlung".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems around 1896 by Tesla from here http://pubs.rsna.org/doi/full/10.1148/rg.284075206